# Grouping pandas dataframe and collecting multiple values into sets

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-munging

Assume that I have the following data frame `df1`:

```
     A    B  C   D 
0  foo  one  1  0
1  bar  two  2  1
2  foo  two  3  0
3  bar  two  4  1
4  foo  two  5  0
5  bar  two  6  1
6  foo  one  7  0
7  foo  two  8  1
```

I would like to turn it into a dataframe `df2` like this:

```
A     B            C                 D             
foo  [one,two]  [1,3,5,7,8]          0
bar  [two]          [2,4,6]          1
```

More precisely:

- grouped by `A`, i.e. column `A` is the index and in every row the value of `A` is unique
- column `B` and `C` contain the aggregate set of values that occur. For `A = "foo"`, `B` was either `"one"` or `"two"`, while for `"bar"` it was only `"two"`.

  - logically, this should be a set with every value that occurs being present exactly once. It could be a Python `set`, but I am also asking what the most elegant way is to represent this with pandas
- column `D` does not contain sets, because for `foo` `D` is always 0 and for `bar` it is always 1. If there is always a 1:1 relationship between the index value and a column value, then the column should not contain sets.

I expected there to be a one-line aggregation a la `df1.groupby("A").aggregate_like_this()`, but I had no luck so far finding it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `groupby` + `agg`:

```
f = {'B' : lambda x: np.unique(x).tolist(), 
     'C' : lambda x: np.unique(x).tolist(), 
     'D' : 'first'
}

df.groupby('A', as_index=False).agg(f).reindex(columns=df.columns)

     A           B                C  D
0  bar       [two]        [2, 4, 6]  1
1  foo  [one, two]  [1, 3, 5, 7, 8]  0
```

---

If you cannot determine in advance what values of `A` have a 1:1 relationship with `D`, check so with `groupby` + `nunique` and then filter your dataset accordingly.

```
x = df.groupby('A').D.nunique().eq(1)
df = df[df.A.isin(x[x].index)]
df

     A    B  C  D
1  bar  two  2  1
3  bar  two  4  1
5  bar  two  6  1

df.groupby('A', as_index=False).agg(f).reindex(columns=df.columns)

     A      B          C  D
0  bar  [two]  [2, 4, 6]  1
```

Comment: Here I need to know beforehand that column D has this 1:1 relationship with the index value. This means I need to test manually for every column. Is there a way let pandas do this automatically?

Comment: You write `{'D': 'first'}`, telling pandas to take the first value for column `D`, because I told you that column `D` has this property that there is only one value of `D` for each value of `A`. But what if we don't know this?

Comment: @clstaudt It will blindly take the first value, whether we know the relationship between D and A or not. In case there are no unique values, what do you want to do?

Comment: Ideally, I would like the aggregation to figure out if there is a 1:1 relationship between the index value and the column value, and therefore only create a column of sets if it is necessary. Of course this can be done in postprocessing, by checking if the result column contains only sets of size 1 and then converting them back to values. But that's a lot of manual coding, I would expect pandas to have a more concise way.

Comment: maybe `df.groupby('A').agg(lambda x : list(set(x)))
`

Comment: @Wen That's an option, but I think `np.unique` is faster than `set` on large arrays... furthermore `D` cannot become a column of lists.

Comment: base on his sample data , that is set contain [0,1] in one group .. :-)

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ You very likely did, but I have to ask for a bit of patience because I reproduce every answer with running code before accepting it and I haven't gotten around yet.